# TestNG, 0 or multiples parameters from a xml file

Tags: java, testng

i'm using the testNG framework. I have tests that can have parameter or not.
By exemple i could have the following xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
   <test name="FlowTest0">
       <parameter name="node" value="http://192.168.117.135:5555/wd/hub"/>
       <parameter name="name" value="nameTest0"/>
       <parameter name="direction" value="IN"/>
       <classes>
           <class name="selenium.test.flow.FlowSaveTest"/>
       </classes>
   </test>
   </suite>
```

Or i could have this one :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
   <test name="FlowTest0">
       <parameter name="node" value="http://192.168.117.135:5555/wd/hub"/>
       <classes>
           <class name="selenium.test.flow.FlowSaveTest"/>
       </classes>
   </test>
   </suite>
```

Or no parameters at all or a lot more.
Then in my test case i get the parameters this way :

```
@Parameters({"name", "direction"})
public void initTest(String name, String direction) {
    //code of the method
}
```

What i want is to be able to pass a variable number of value depending what i have in the xml. Can i do this with the testNG parameters annotation ?

EDIT 1 :

I would expect something like the declaration of the printf declaration in C, something like :

```
@Parameters("node", Something that will get all the paramaters)
@BeforeTest
public void initTest(Object ...) {

}
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of what you expect?

Comment: Yes i will edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [inject](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection) the [`ITestContext`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestContext.html#getCurrentXmlTest--) and get all attributes from there:

```
@Test
public void initTest(ITestContext context) {
    Map<String, String> params = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getAllParameters();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake, the initTest also have the @BeforeTest annotation, maybe it changes something, i will edit my question.

Comment: But what if the parameter is not a String ? Because before i had some arguement in my method that was boolean and not only String

Comment: TestNG parameters are always strings. The conversion is your business. But your test is supposed to know the type so it should not be a problem.